# move_uploaded_file returns false always when uploading file from Node server

Tags: php, node.js

I am sending a file from node server to Api in PHP.

```
$name=dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/location/uploads/'.$files["image"]["name"];
if(!(move_uploaded_file($files["image"]["tmp_name"], $name))){
    $errmsg.= '5';
}
```

But **move_uploaded_file** returns false everytime without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are stored in `$_FILES`, see example code on the [move_uploaded_file manual page](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file#refsect1-function.move-uploaded-file-examples).

Check it with

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Somewhere in there is an `error` key.